# Pre-validate list of API testing request URLs

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, api

I want to pre-validate a list of API testing request URLs below using Python regex.

The following list of URLS/requests strings 'R' has 2 parts:

1. the request and
2. the validity of this request.

The regex code works correctly except for the first 19 and the last 3 (22-24), but not for requests 20-21 (see comments within list def).

I am sure there are more efficient ways to do the match, but they gave me similar results. So I am just keeping my example simple.

```
import re
R = [
# these are invalid and fail regex match
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/x,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?x,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?=,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?x=,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries&,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries&x,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries&=,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries&x=,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries&x=x,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?code=AU?,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=Australia?x,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=Australia?=,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=Australia?x=,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=Australia?x=x,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=Australia&,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=Australia&x,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=Australia&=,bad",
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=Australia&x=,bad",

# these are valid requests and fail regex match
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries,good", # 20
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=Australia,good", # 21

# these are valid and pass regex match
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?code=AU&name=Australia,good", # 22
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?name=New Zealand&calling_code=64,good", # 23    
"http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries?code=AU&name=Australia&capital=Canberra,good", #24   
]
for r in R:
    divs.split(",")
    m = re.match(r'http://127.0.0.1:5000/countries[\?[\s\w]{1,}=[\s\w]{1,}[\&[\s\w]{1,}=[\s\w]{1,}]{0,}]{0,1}', divs[0])    
    res = "good" if m != None else "bad"
    print(divs[0] + " should be " + divs[1] + " and is " + res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex:

`^http://127\.0\.0\.1:5000/countries(?:\?\w+=[\s\w]+(?:&\w+=[\s\w]+)*)?$ /gm`

Note that:

1. The complete thing after `countries` is optional.
2. `.` needs to be escaped since it has a special meaning in the regex world
3. URL parameters are key value pairs with left hand side matching by `\w` and right hand side by a combination of `\s\w`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YccNOj/6)

Comment: Awesome! ... Thanks very much!